# Code works only if written inside the input but not with echo in a while loop

Tags: jquery, html

I know that the title I wrote can be confusing but I find it difficult to find a suitable title to explain the problem well.

I will do it here in the text, I have a code that calculates through inputs and a script a mathematical calculation starting from the figure that is written inside the input, the code is working and you can test it by copying and pasting

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <input required type="text" name="price" value="<?php echo $row['releprev_preventivo']; ?>" id="price" class="form-control">

<script>
    jQuery("#price").on("change paste keyup", function() {
        var price = $(this).val();
        var percent = 47;
        var percentInDecimal = percent / 100;
        var percent_two = percentInDecimal * price;
        var subtraction = price - percent_two;
        var division = subtraction / 2;
        console.log(division);
        jQuery('#importo').html(price);
        jQuery('#tasse').html(percent_two);
        jQuery('#netto_tasse').html(subtraction);
        jQuery('#res_netto_tasse').html(subtraction);
        jQuery('#result').html(division);
    });
</script>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="importo"></th>
        <th style="text-align: center">sottratto a</th>
        <th id="tasse"></th>
        <th>(47%)Tasse</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="netto_tasse"></td>
        <td>Netto tasse</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="res_netto_tasse"></td>
        <td>/ 2 (Diviso al 50%)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="result"></td>
        <td>Guadagno</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the code works perfectly if obviously we remove the part of the value where I do an echo of a result, then writing a certain mathematical figure the consequent arithmetic calculations are applied, and everything works perfectly, I only have a problem that when instead I do the echo of the result , then I open the page and inside the input I don't write a number but the number is displayed by the echo, the calculation is not performed and I find myself with a table devoid of data, how can I make the input perform the calculation by not writing nothing but having the default value?

Comment: Add `.trigger('change')` to the end of your jQuery. This will trigger the event when the page loads and fill the  data based on the default value

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry because I'm not practical where should I add this in my code?

Comment: <?php if(!empty($row['releprev_preventivo']){ echo $row['releprev_preventivo']; }else{ echo ' ';} ?> Try like this-

Comment: @user12944651 I added an answer for you

Comment: @HiteshKumar I think you've misunderstood the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `trigger()` at the end of your code to raise the event on the element when the page loads to force the calculation to run at that time.

Also note there's a couple of improvements you can make to the code. Firstly, use the `input` event as this covers all three events you're using now. Then be wary of using strings in mathematical calculations. You can get away with it in some occasions due to type coercion, as in this case, but it's better to explicityl cast your values to integers or floats. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#price").on("input", function() {
    var price = parseFloat($(this).val()); // or, if it's not a floating point number: parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    var percent_two = price * 0.47; // no need to work out the percentage manually if it's hardcoded anyway
    var subtraction = price - percent_two;
    var division = subtraction / 2;

    $('#importo').html(price);
    $('#tasse').html(percent_two);
    $('#netto_tasse').html(subtraction);
    $('#res_netto_tasse').html(subtraction);
    $('#result').html(division);
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input required type="text" name="price" value="100.00" id="price" class="form-control" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <th id="importo"></th>
    <th style="text-align: center">sottratto a</th>
    <th id="tasse"></th>
    <th>(47%)Tasse</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="netto_tasse"></td>
    <td>Netto tasse</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="res_netto_tasse"></td>
    <td>/ 2 (Diviso al 50%)</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="result"></td>
    <td>Guadagno</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You may also want to consider using `toFixed(2)` on the output values, if these figures are prices.